# jquery sortable: get list behavior without an <ul>?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

This plugin (jQuery UI's Sortable) gives me behavior I prefer if I use a list, but I need divs in order to get the formatting I want. Specifically, with a list it gives me good positioning, and it knows the right direction to shift things out of the way in. Everything works better with a list - except the formatting stuff I need from the CSS.

I know you can use `connectWith` to modify the sorting behavior, but it's not at all clear to me how. It's also not clear to me if I can modify the "other objects getting out of the way" behavior with some similar option. It works beautifully with a list and is almost worthless with divs.

Also, if you know how to solve my list vs. div formatting problem, I asked another question about that here:

[is it even possible to expand a (horizontal) list's background with ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059606/is-it-even-possible-to-expand-a-horizontal-lists-background-with-ajax)

Comment: Any specific css you need that can only apply to `<div>`, but not to list? With css, you can manipulate it the same way you manipulate `<div>`, make it float, remove the bullet, manipulate margin and padding, etc. Please provide the example of your code, or the URL of the page.

Comment: it's solved now, but the problem was due to how floats relate to the box model. some good comments on the other question, click the link for mas informacíon, thx

Comment: I have give my answers there too :)